# MongoDB - db.save()- Type Error- db.collection.save is not a function

Tags: database, mongodb, typeerror, mql

When I try to make a save function, then it goes an error.
ie. I tried db.collection.save()
my db is test and my collection name is myCol

```
test> db.myCol.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62dd5dfd976a6f6126179768"),
    name: 'J',
    totVal: 5,
    values: [ 'Hi', 'Hello', 'How' ],
    valMin: 15
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62dd738a976a6f6126179769"),
    name: 'K',
    values: [ 'Hi', 'Hello', 'How' ],
    totVal: 5,
    valMin: 15
  }
]
```

```
test> db.myCol.save({"_id": ObjectId(62dd738a976a6f6126179769),"name":"New Element"})
Uncaught:
SyntaxError: Identifier directly after number. (1:33)

> 1 | db.myCol.save({"_id": ObjectId(62dd738a976a6f6126179769),"name":"New Element"})
    |                                  ^
  2 |

test>
```

tried this tooo

```
test> db.myCol.save({"_id": ObjectId("62dd738a976a6f6126179769"),"name":"New Element"})
TypeError: db.myCol.save is not a function
test>
```

Comment: `save()` is deprecated as of 4.2. Which version of MongoDB are you using? Use `db.myCol.replaceOne({"_id": ObjectId("62dd738a976a6f6126179769"),"name":"New Element"})` instead.

Comment: It's partially working,
But not working, and error is this.
`{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 0,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0
}`

Answer (score 1):

It's done using this:
Beacause- save is depricated and use replaceOne() instead of save().

```
db.myCol.replaceOne({"_id": ObjectId("62dd738a976a6f6126179769")},{"name":"New Element"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `myCol` schema defines `_id`:

```js
const myCol = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  totVal: Number,
  values: [String],
  valMin: Number
});
```

Comment: I'm learning mongoDB using CMD, and it's still not working

Comment: How are you defining the schema of the collection via the command line?

Comment: I don't know. I just learning,
I tried like this,
`db.myCol.save({_id: ObjectId("62dd738a976a6f6126179769"),"name":"New Element"})`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using User.find instead of User.findOne and not really drilling down to the particular object.